# Failure to connect to postgres docker container running From Host Machine

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm running Django app with Postgres via Docker Compose, I'v modified the port to be used as 5433 instead of 5432. Django application inside the container is able to connect to Postgres db via port 5433 But when i try to connect to DB from my host machine using PgAdmin i got error, even via CLI as well.

```bash
$ psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U django_user
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5433 failed: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

I then added PGadmin insider docker compose, and PG admin from docker-compose is also able to connect to postgres db but still can't from host machine.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: "3.8"
volumes:
    postgres_data:

services:
    web:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            target: local
        container_name: django_backend
        restart: always
        env_file: .env.local
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - .:/app
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: postgres:latest
        container_name: django_db
        restart: always
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=django_user
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=django_pass
            - POSTGRES_DB=django_db
            - PGDATA=/tmp/pgdata
        expose:
            - "5433"
        ports:
            - "5433:5432"
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/tmp/pgdata
        command: -p 5433
    pgadmin-compose:
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        container_name: django_pgadmin
        environment:
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "admin@django.co"
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "test123!"
        ports:
            - "8085:80"
        depends_on:
            - db
```

Output of the `docker-compose ps` command

[image]

Any hint, what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue in your ports mappings; the following:

```yaml
db:
        image: postgres:latest
        # ...
        expose:
            - "5433"
        ports:
            - "5433:5432"
        command: -p 5433
```

means pg will run on port 5433, but you're exposing port 5432 to your host. So, when you try to reach 5433 from your host, it redirects to port 5432 of the container, and nothing is listening on port 5432 because pg is started with command `-p 5433`; hence the error.

You should write:

```yaml
db:
        image: postgres:latest
        # ...
        expose:
            - "5433"
        ports:
            - "5433:5433"
        command: -p 5433
```

As [@David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) has pointed out in the comments, you can even let pg listen on the default port (without specifying `-p` option), and remove the `expose` section:

```yaml
db:
        image: postgres:latest
        # ...
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
```

That way you could connect to the default port from your host:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U django_user
```

Comment: Also consider removing the `command: -p 5433` line so that PostgreSQL listens on its default port, and changing the Django configuration to match; since each container has a separate network environment there won't be a conflict here.  Then the original `ports:` line will work.  `expose:` does nothing and you should just delete it either way.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, I've updated my answer to include your comment!

Comment: I'v PG installed locally, but don't want to use that for the projects. So i'v to expose those on different ports. But your highlighted code is works fine.